# Understanding matrix products

Tags: matrix, numerical-methods

If I have two n*n matrices A and B and a vector C,how would I compute the product of A -1Bc ? 
I know how how to get A-1 by doing Lu decomposition pf A but how do I translate this into an efficient computation for products

Comment: This smells like homework...

Answer (score 0):

No need to explicitly compute the inverse of A; first, compute d=Bc, which is a Matrix-Vector product (much faster than a Matrix-Matrix product). Then solve the linear equation Ax=d for x, using the LU decomposition of A. Then x will be A^-1Bc.